# Error:Drop down all elements when click on one element with same class

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple dropdowns and its will drop all element when I click one. I try to use for loop , but It doesn't work. The second loop not working// when I change [i] -> [j] it's work, but it drop all
Below is just 1 of many "route-option" div

```js
var chooseBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("route-choose");
for (var i = 0; i < chooseBtn.length; i++) {
  chooseBtn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var map = document.getElementsByClassName("tft97");
    for (var j = 0; j < map.length; j++) {
      map[i].classList.toggle("hide");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="route-option">
  <div class="route-container">
    <button class="route-choose" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <img src="/img/icon/pokeball.png" width="34px" height="34px">
        </button>
  </div>
  <div class="tft97">
    <div class="seat-container ">

      <div class="seat-map">
        <div class="seat-table">
          <div class="seat-table-container">
            <table class="table">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="seat-num" id="seat-nu" style="cursor: pointer;">
                    <img src="/img/icon/armchair.png">
                    <h4>1</h4>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="seat-footer">
        <div class="bill-info">
          Tong tien:
          <span class="total">vnd</span>
        </div>
        <button class="btn-check" onclick="location.href='/Untitled-1.html'">
            Tiep tuc
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify, ideally with some samples.   Your title says "drop down all elements" (as a requirement) then your questions says "but drop[drops] all" - implying drop down all is incorrect.

Comment: I'm so sorry because of my english

Comment: Ok, so assuming the issue is that all drop down and you don't want all to drop down - this matches what your code says it would do.   So what *do* you want?   When clicking on one (of many) route-choose then show a *related* one (of many) tft97?   What's the relation between them?  Need that HTML.

Comment: @freedomn-m I have an error that Multiple dropdowns with same class just drop the first element when I clicked , others not work. I change my js :" querySelector --> querySelectorAll" it's working but the Multiple dropdowns will drop all when I click any button on it. I change my code in second loop map[j] ---> map[i] it's doesn't work

Comment: I already add html @freedomn-m

Comment: I did by change var i to let i

Comment: With only one route-choose and only one tft97 it's still a little hard to determine what you're trying to do.  I would image that in the click event of route-choose you would use DOM relative navigation ([closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to get the `route-option` then locate the tft97 within that element.